# coroutine that is only running on final iteration c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

my method moves all units in an array one tile at the same time once per iteration until it gets to its final destination however when it runs it only moves the unit from the penultimate tile to the final tile. the enumerator is passing control back to the method without having moved the unit on all other tiles, im not sure how to stop this.

```
void MoveAllUnits()
{
    coroutineRunning = true;

    List<Unit> UnitsToMove = new List<Unit>();

    int longestPath = 0; //finds the lost journey amongst availble units

    for (int k = 0; k < units.Count; k++)
    {

        if (longestPath < units[k].path.Count)
        {
            units[k].pathLength = units[k].path.Count;
            longestPath = units[k].path.Count;
        }
    }
    longestPath--;


    for (int i = 0; i < longestPath; i++) //step iterator
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < units.Count; j++) //unit iterator
        {
            if (units[j] != null) //check for null list element
            {
                if (units[j].path.Count > 0) // check that unit has a path to follow
                {

                    if (i < (units[j].path.Count - 1))//check if unit has any more steps on path
                    {
                        if (i == 0) //inhabited value is changed to false on the first move
                        {
                            gridArray[units[j].startX, units[j].startY].GetComponent<GridStats>().inhabited = false;
                            gridArray[units[j].startX, units[j].startY].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;
                        }

                        UnitsToMove.Add(units[j]); // adds the unit to a list of units to move that iteration

                        if (i == (units[j].path.Count - 2)) //inhabited value is changes to true on the final move, changes the units start tile to current tile
                        {
                            gridArray[units[j].endX, units[j].endY].GetComponent<GridStats>().inhabited = true;
                            units[j].startX = units[j].endX;
                            units[j].startY = units[j].endY;

                            unitArray[units[j].endX, units[j].endY] = units[j];
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach(Unit bub in UnitsToMove) // cycles through unitsToMove, moving each unit one space
        {
            StartCoroutine(Move(bub, i));
           
        }
        UnitsToMove.Clear();
    }
    coroutineRunning = false;

}

IEnumerator Move(Unit unit, int step)
{
    float interp = 0;

    while (interp < 1)
    {
        interp += .07f;
        unit.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(new Vector3(unit.path[step].transform.position.x, unit.path[step].transform.position.y, unit.path[step].transform.position.z), new Vector3(unit.path[step + 1].transform.position.x, unit.path[step + 1].transform.position.y, unit.path[step + 1].transform.position.z), interp);
        yield return null;

    }
```

Comment: If your question involves Unity3d, you should add that tag. Please also read [mcve].

Comment: I understand your question may be clear to you, but please take a moment to consider an audience that has no familiarity with your program. For example, you refer to a "Tile," but there is actually nothing named "Tile" in your code, so we actually don't know what you're talking about. What is a "Tile" and what does it mean to move a unit to a tile? Are you simply talking about positions within an array?

Comment: apologies, yes, i have a grid of tiles that are stored in a two dimensional array, any more tips to make my question clearer would be appreciated.

Comment: @DavidWard are you sure the Coroutine is actually not running, or it simply doesn't look like it? Try putting in a `Debug.Log(unit.gameObject.name);` and see what happens